# Return type of a method in Objective-C can not be achieved by Clang python binding

Tags: python, objective-c, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

I want to parse some source code in Objective-C using Clang Python binding. It works except that I can not get the return type of a method, which it is a primitive type.

When the kind of cursor is OBJC_INSTANCE_METHOD_DECL, what I get from the property result_type.kind is always TypeKind.INVALID. Meanwhile, when there is no argument in a method, and the return type of the method is a primitive type. It can not get any child from the cursor. However, when the return type is not a primitive type, it can be found as a child of a cursor.

Does someone have an idea, how can I get the cursor of the return value?